# Unit test with HttpWebClient or RestSharp

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository-pattern

I am trying to find a way to write the unit test for the "CheckSomething" method, but i am having a very difficult time figuring out what to do with the RestClient object i am instantiating in the method.

Should I abstract away the RestClient, and put the Interface dependency at the class level and injected from withint he constructor?? If i go with this route, does that mean I have to interface out all the dependencies ??

```
public class SomeRepository : IXRepository
{
    public SomeRepository()
    {
    }

    public bool CheckSomething()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("someurl");

        var request = new RestRequest("resourceX/{name}", Method.GET);
        request.AddUrlSegment("name", "ABC");
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) return false;
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) return true;

        throw new Exception("Something is messed up");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a class level RestClient field in SomeRepository, you can use method injection, and add a RestClient parameter to the CheckSomething method. You can then mock the RestClient for your unit tests.

```
public bool CheckSomething(RestClient restClient)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("resourceX/{name}", Method.GET);
    request.AddUrlSegment("name", "ABC");
    var response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) return false;
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) return true;

    throw new Exception("Something is messed up");
}
```

If that were my code, I would want to test the following things:

1. Has the RestRequest that was passed into the RestClient.Execute method been properly setup.
2. Does the method return true or false based on the response.StatusCode
3. Does any other status code result in an exception being thrown.

If that is all you need to test, then the only thing you need to mock is the RestClient, which means you could easily just use method injection, or constructor or property injection.

Comment: decided not to write unit test for method that basically wrap the httpclient.